# Create many ssh users with PK on many hosts

Tags: ssh

I want to add one one or many new users with their public keys on many host (Where I have password-less root ssh). Sure I can make it manually. Is there way to make it aromatically?

Comment: While burning incense maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
init-user-on-host() # <username> <id_rsa.pub file> <remote host>
{
    cat $2 | ssh root@$3 \
        "set -x; adduser --quiet --gecos '' --disabled-password $1;" \
        " su -l $1 -c 'mkdir -p .ssh;" \
        "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys;" \
        "ls -RA; cat .ssh/authorized_keys' "
    ssh $1@$3 echo OK
}

init-users-on-hosts()
{
    for u in $users; do
        for h in $hosts; do
            init-user-on-host $u $u.id_rsa.pub $h
        done
    done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do it programmatically. I've written scripts to push out users and credentials/keys from a control server to other systems on demand, and automation software like Puppet, Chef and CFEngine do it as well using a pull mechanism.

You could probably also tie it in with LDAP. (https://serverfault.com/questions/653792/ssh-key-authentication-using-ldap#653793)

Comment: Thanks. I also can write yet another script and wonder if somebody already wrote it. Automation software are interesting, but I am looking for something more lightweight and easy to use.

Comment: @costa you really have not provided sufficient case details (is this one off or periodic? What security model do you use? Are the machines dissimilar in access requirements/os? How good are your scripting skills? Why is something like puppet not a good fit? I can ask my work about me publishing my script for maintaining users for you but do you really want to trust $random internet person$ with the keys to your kingdom?